# R1C1 Array formula adding functions

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I can't figure out what's wrong with below formula.
When I put INDEX function once it's working but fails when I sum it with another INDEX.
Could you please help.

```
.Cells(i, 13).FormulaR1C1 = "=INDEX('LISTA'!R20C2:R2000C2000, MATCH( ""Work1"",'LISTA'!R20C1:R2000C1,0),MATCH(R[]C2&R[]C3,'LISTA'!R17C2:R17C2000&'LISTA'!R13C2:R13C2000,0))" + "INDEX('LISTA'!R20C2:R2000C2000, MATCH( ""Work2"",'LISTA'!R20C1:R2000C1,0),MATCH(R[]C2&R[]C3,'LISTA'!R17C2:R17C2000&'LISTA'!R13C2:R13C2000,0))""

.Cells(i, 13).FormulaArray = .Cells(i, 13).Formula
```

Comment: I'm unclear on whether the `+` indicates a sum or a string concatenation.

Comment: There are mismatches in the MATCH function(s)'s lookup ranges. Saying `'LISTA'!R17C2:R17C2000&'LISTA'!R13C2:R13C2000` is like saying `B17:BXXX2000&B13:BXXX2000`. The concatenated ranges should be of the same size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both Index functions separately are working, then i would try it with

```
=SUM(Index1,Index2)
```

and if i see it correctly youve quoted the fomulas wrong.

```
.Cells(i, 13).FormulaR1C1 = "=INDEX('LISTA'!R20C2:R2000C2000, MATCH( ""Work1"",'LISTA'!R20C1:R2000C1,0),MATCH(R[]C2&R[]C3,'LISTA'!R17C2:R17C2000&'LISTA'!R13C2:R13C2000,0)) + INDEX('LISTA'!R20C2:R2000C2000, MATCH( ""Work2"",'LISTA'!R20C1:R2000C1,0),MATCH(R[]C2&R[]C3,'LISTA'!R17C2:R17C2000&'LISTA'!R13C2:R13C2000,0))"
```

An easy way to convert formulas to r1c1 style is write the working formula to a cell, copy it and then record a new macro and just paste the formula to a cell.

This is my favorite way of writing formulas to r1c1